# Ubuntu Login for first time

Tags: ubuntu, login

I installed Ubuntu 10.04, but when I tried to login I found out that my keyboard is inactive.
I searched the Internet and learned how to activate the on-screen keyboard. But, when I activate the on-screen keyboard, it immediately disappears.

I don't know what's happening but need to login into Ubuntu.

Comment: was the keyboard OK when you installed Ubuntu?

Comment: BTW I think you meant "Ubuntu 10.04", which is "the Ubuntu that was released in April, 2010" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I meant 10.04, I fixed it. 
I just needed to shut it down and boot it again. Then the onscreen keyboard would appear.
But you would need to use the onscreen keyboard every time you would login on your Ubuntu box.
You can fix this using following instructions:

1. First log in to your Ubuntu 10.04 install.
2. Open a terminal.
3. Type `sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup`
4. Follow the instructions you see on your terminal.
5. Enjoy using Ubuntu.

Comment: now that you have found your own answer, please mark it as "accepted" by clicking on the tick

Answer (score 0):

This is a shot in the dark, but you could try adding `i8042.nopnp` to your boot line in grub.

I swore I updated my answer...

When you boot up, it should display the grub menu. I forget the exact commands, but you hit like e to edit the line, then go down to where it says kernel= and hit e again to edit that line. Add `i8042.nopnp` to the end of that line. Then hit enter, then either b or ctrl-x, I forget which.

Comment: what is that, explain it more

Comment: how should i do that?